# What's the best way to cut through this wall?

Tags: framing, construction, stucco

I am adding insulation+drywall between open rafters. What's the best way (tool, blade/bit, technique, other advice) to get through these wall layers for ventilation? (I'll put mesh and grilles over the stucco holes.)

There's a 2x4, a 2x6, builder's paper, and stucco over lathe. I'm not sure if the 2x4 (front) is structural or was just a surface for mounting the appearance board that was nailed to it.

I could easily just tear into it, but I'm sure there's a "right" way that I don't know about. I have the basic power tools (e.g., recip saw).

[image: Framing/roof assembly]

Comment: I'm not sure what wall you're referring to. What you've shown us in the photo appears to ask be structural, and probably shouldn't be touched until an engineer has confirmed h that it is not load-bearing.... And even so I don't see anything you would _want_ to cut away....

Comment: @keshlam, yes, it's an exterior wall, so is load bearing--but the holes will be above the top plate, in the blocking between the rafters. My reading of the residential code is that there needs to be ventilation to the outside if the space is enclosed.

Comment: Ask the building inspector how to do it... They provide amazing help when you ask the proper approach to take in advance... It kinda goes to their head.